# How to parse yml in curl correctly?

Tags: curl, circleci

Trying to create a Context in CircleCI via API. Reference document: https://circleci.com/docs/api/v2/#tag/Context

I have created a personal api token and encoded into base64 as per requirement, to use in basic auth command.

I am using curl command like below:

```
  name: "Create Context"
  command:
    curl --request POST \
    --url https://circleci.com/api/v2/context \
    --header 'authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    --header 'content-type:' 'application/json' \
    --data '{"name":"string","owner":{"id":"string","type":"organization"}}'
```

I am getting error like below:

```
Unable to parse YAML
mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 23, column 36:
                --header 'authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ...
```

I tried having double quotes around for escape character in that line but still same error.
can you please suggest right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiline string value syntax in YAML is different. There is no backslash-escapes-newline logic there. It should go:

```
name: "Create Context"
  command: >
    curl --request POST 
    --url https://circleci.com/api/v2/context 
    --header 'authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    --header 'content-type:' 'application/json'
    --data '{"name":"string","owner":{"id":"string","type":"organization"}}'
```

The end of the string is indicated by indentation, as YAML does.

Note that YAML parsing is not being done by CURL itself. You have a `curl` command inside YAML, not the other way around. As for the surrounding piece of software that *is* parsing YAML, it's unclear from the question.